# IronPython use namespace without import

Tags: .net, namespaces, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

Is it possible in IronPython to use a kind of inline namespace? For example:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Test")
```

If i execute the code from above, get the following error: `name 'System' is not defined`. Or do i always have to use the following code?

```
import System
System.Console.WriteLine("Test")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My assumption that you are running this from the interactive console not embedded in a C# application. The interactive console implicitly loads mscorlib and System dlls but does not import them. So you will need to import System before referencing it.

You can also do the following if you only what Console.

from System import Console
Console.WriteLine("Test")

if you wanted a to reference another .NET namespace in a different dll other than mscorlib or System you will need the following
import clr
clr.AddReference()
import

Comment: It's from my own C# app :)